# Word Meaning "A single thing that's an indicator of greater overall trends"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word that means "a single thing or a subset of things that could be used to represent greater overall trends"?

I work for a bookseller. The other day I was discussing a subset of several books that have consistently been bestsellers for the past few months. These books could be used to represent sales trends on a larger scale - something like "blue chip" books. In the conversation I referred to them as "bellwether books", but later on I doubted this was the correct usage of the word. "Bellwether" is defined as "an indicator or predictor of something". Is there a more appropriate word?

Comment: Somehow I feel reminded of [swallows](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one_swallow_does_not_a_summer_make). And snowdrops or May bells (I'm always getting them confused)...

Comment: For *negative* trends, there's also "canary in the coal mine", an early warning of things being bad.

Comment: If you're not looking for a complicated word, "sign" is fine. It's the exact definition of an indicator of something bigger or greater  : " a dark cloud is a sign of rain" " a poor sale of blue chip books is a sign of poor sales to come" "

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Bellwether* seems like an excellent usage for the situation you describe, because when you're talking about trends (at least, other than retrospectively) you're somewhat inherently talking about prediction.  If prediction weren't relevant to the situation I might use *exemplar* or *typifier*, or perhaps something like *quintessential example* if I were wont to wax verbose.

Those are all for a single item; for a subset of items, *representative sample* comes thundering out of the land of statistics to dominate the lexical landscape.

Comment: Good point. I should have specified that I was talking about them retrospectively. That is to say, if those books weren't selling well during a given period it stands to reason that sales overall were weak during the same period.

Comment: @michaelmichael: Bellwether can still be a good term when speaking retrospectively, too; you can look back and see that those books' sales *would* have been a good predictor of the overall market if you'd been looking at them that way.  I think you picked the right word on the spot, honestly. :)

Comment: +1 Bellwether is great.  Also, *marker* is often used in news reports when using, for instance, a single business category to predict general economic trends.